# Pyautogui keyDown function is not working

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, ui-automation, pyautogui

I've tried all types of tricks like using the hotkey function, (pressing down ctrl, pressing v, and pressing up ctrl), every combination of above

```
import tkinter as tk
import pyautogui

run = False
    
def start():
        global stopbutton
        global run
        global startbuttona
        run = True
        pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
        pyautogui.keyDown('V')
        startbutton.place_forget()
        stopbutton.place(x=150, y=400, width=230, height=20)

def stop():
    global run
    global stopbutton
    global startbutton
    run  = False
    pyautogui.keyUp('V')
    pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')
    stopbutton.place_forget()
    startbutton.place(x=150, y=400, width=230, height=20)



window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.title("Rickroll spammer")
startlabel = tk.Label(window, text="Start abomination", font=("Courier", 30))
startbutton = tk.Button(window, text="Start", command=start)
stopbutton = tk.Button(window, text="Stop", command=stop)
startbutton.place(x=150, y=400, width=230, height=20)
startlabel.place(x=50, y=240)


window.mainloop()
```

I also tried using pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')

(I tried to pass the keys argument in both caps and lower)